# How to memoize nested function in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memoization, usecallback

How to memoize nested function?
For e.g., if we have following memoized components App, Test, OtherComponent

```
const App = React.memo(() => {
  const handleChange = useCallback((rowData) => (option) => {},[]);
  return <Test data={data} handleChange={handleChange} />;
});

const Test = React.memo(({ data, handleChange }) =>{
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((rowData) => (
        <OtherComp handleChange={handleChange(rowData)} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
});

const OtherComp = React.memo(({ handleChange }) =>{});
```

`React.memo` will work only if we pass it memoized functions/objects.
If we use `useCallback`, it won’t memoize inner function and `React.memo`  won’t work for OtherComponent.

Comment: You are missing the dependency array as the second argument to `useCallback`. Refer to the [documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useCallback#usecallback) for more information. It also seems like the `<Test />` component is missing the `data` prop which will throw a `TypeError` here.

Comment: The code is just for example. However, updated.